# How many $5$-digit numbers are there with digits $abcde$ such that $a < b < c \leq d \leq e$?

Tags: combinatorics, permutations

> How many $5$-digit numbers are there with digits $abcde$ such that $a < b < c \leq d \leq e$?

I know that if all of them were distinct, then the answer will be $C(9,5)$. However, there are some "less than or equal to" notations, so I do not know how to approach it. I need help. Thanks in advance.

Comment: If all of them were distinct, the answer would just be $\binom 95$.

Comment: @MishaLavrov little mistake , thanks

Comment: Does $a$ have to be nonzero?

Comment: @JukkaKohonen yeap , to be 5 digit , it has to be nonzero

Comment: The question doesn't make sense to me. How many numbers are there such that $abcde$ what?

Comment: I believe their English is in slight disarray and they just meant how many 5 digit numbers are there in the form $abcde$. @AdamRubinson

Comment: Hopefully the euestion is clearer now.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Hint: If you replace $d$ by $d+1$, and $e$ by $e+2$ in your number, then you are looking for all distinct digits, and now the digits are at most 11 (instead of at most 9).

Comment: Great hint (I upvoted) . I think you meant to say that the digits are at most 11 (instead of at most 9)

Comment: Oops, of course (originally between 1 and 9, now between 1 and 11). Thanks, will correct!

Comment: @Jukka Kohonen: **(1)** I don't see how $11$ can be considered as a **digit**. **(2)** Only part of the *abcde* is strictly increasing

Comment: true blue anil: (1) I don't see the problem. You can call them hexadecimal digits if you will, or just integers. It does not matter. Once you have such five integers $a < b < c < d' < e'$, with $e' \le 11$, you can turn them back to a solution of the original problem with $d=d'-1$ and $e=e'-2$. (2) That's exactly why the transformation was applied only to $d$ and $e$.

Comment: Nice  shortcut (+1).

Comment: @JukkaKohonen so smart way +1

Comment: @JukkaKohonen correct me if i am wrong , to make them stricly increasing we make additions such as d+1 , e+2 .So , the selection set converted from {1,2,...,8,9} into {1,2,...,10,11} , so  we select 5 numbers in the set of {1,2,...,10,11} to construct a construction such that $x_1 < x_2 < x_3 < x_4 < x_5$ .As a result , you say that by doing  that replacement we turned question to be making selection form in the set ${1,2,...,10,11}$ to construct $x_1 < x_2 < x_3 < x_4 < x_5$ . Namely, these are different questions , but their solutions are the same like combinatorical proof of binom theorems

Comment: @JukkaKohonen because , we can give different interpretetitons to  any binomial theorems

Comment: @JukkaKohonen Is my understanding correct ?

Comment: @JukkaKohonen moreover , if the question were $a \leq b \leq c < d \leq e$ , then $b'=b+1 , c'=c+2 , e'=e+3$ , so $a<b'<c'<d<e'$ .Hence , the answer is $C(12,3)$. Am ı right ?

Comment: @STEWEN: Yes, you have the correct idea! I believe you mean $C(12,5)$ since you are choosing five elements. Then you get 792 which is correct.

Comment: And indeed, although the questions and their solutions are different (with all elements distinct versus some having only $\le$), the fact that you can construct a *bijection* between the solution sets means that the *numbers* of solutions are equal. In combinatorics this is often called a "bijective proof".

Comment: @JukkaKohonen One thing more , i understand why $b'=b+1$ and $c'=c+2$ but why $e'=e+1$ is not correct ? why should i  add $3$ to $e$ , there is not any consecutive $\leq$ symbol in the place of $e$

Comment: Since you have transformed $c$ to $c'=c+2$, you need to similarly transform $d$ to $d'=d+2$ to maintain that $c' < d'$ is equivalent to $c < d$. This in turn has consequences for $e$.

Comment: @JukkaKohonen why did you transform $d$ ? , it is already strictly less than

Comment: Consider $(a,b,c,d,e) = (1,1,1,2,2)$, which is a solution to $a \le b \le c < d \le e$. If you transform to $(a,b',c',d,e') =(1,2,3,2,3)$ (leaving $d$ untransformed), do you have $<$ relation in your new solution between all pairs? No you don't, so you need to fix that.

Comment: @JukkaKohonen ı know i bothered you so much , but this is my last question stuck in mind : why did you constrain $e$ by adding $2$ ,i.e, why did we add $3$ or $7$ or etc to make them strictly increasing. why did you choose the smallest number that make them strictly increasing. By the way , thanks for your answer

Comment: Adding more would make them strictly increasing all right, but that would ruin the bijection. Let's take a simple example with just two digits $(a,b)$, and consider transformed digits $(a, b')$ where $b'=b+3$. Yes, $a \le b$ implies $a<b'$, but not vice versa. So you don't have a bijection between solutions. $(a,b')=(4,5)$ is a solution for $a<b'$, but transform back to $(a,b)=(4,2)$ and you *don't* have a solution for $a \le b$.

Comment: It all boils down to the equivalence (when $a,b$ are integers): $a \le b \Leftrightarrow a < b+1$. It is essential that the implication holds in both directions.

Answer (score 3):

The first thing to note is that if we select *k* distinct digits from *n* digits, the digits can be arranged in a strictly ascending order **in only one way**

We can break up the number string into two parts

**(a):** $a,b,c:\;$ The **ending** digit($c$) can range from $3-9$ and it can be seen that if the **ending digit** $c$ is $n$, say, from the lower digits, there can be $\binom{n-1}2$ selections in strictly ascending order

**(b):** Suppose *c* was $3$, then we have $10-3=7$ digits for the remaining slot $e$ . These slots can either have distinct digits $\binom72$, or identical digits, $7$

Combining the two parts, the formula comes out to

$$\sum_{n=3}^{10}\binom{n-1}2\left[\binom{10-n}2+(10-n)\right] = 462$$

Comment: Not quite. For example, suppose that the third digit is $c=8$. Then your summation is counting $(10-8)^2 = 4$ ways for the final two digits $(d,e)$, but if you simply list the possibilities, you can see that there are only three: 88, 89 and 99. A similar error is in the other terms (that is, when $c<8$) so the sum is overcounting the cases.

Comment: Corrected 3am error after 10am coffee !

Comment: (+1) I also confirmed the numeric value by brute force.

Comment: Yes, now it works! (Coffee helps, ask Erdős.)

Comment: @trueblueanil hmmm nice +1 , by the way for part $b$ you can use combinantion with repetition instead of wrting seperately such that distinct digits + identical digits

Comment: @Bulbasaur: I know, but that would have involved a lengthier explanation, what with a slightly different application of stars and bars.

Answer (score 2):

To find all digits such that $0<a < b < c \leq d \leq e$,

- find all subsets $\{a,b,c,d,e\}$ from $\{1,\ldots,9\}\ $ (w.l.o.g $a<b<c<d<e$) to get all 5 digit numbers, there are $\binom 9   5$ such numbers
- find all subsets $\{a,b,c,e\}$ from $\{1,\ldots,9\}\ $ (w.l.o.g $a<b<c<e$), set $d:=c$ to get all 5 digit numbers such that $a<b<c=d<e$, there are $\binom 9   4$
- find all subsets $\{a,b,c,d\}$ from $\{1,\ldots,9\}\ $ (w.l.o.g $a<b<c<d$), set $e:=d$ to get all 5 digit numbers such that $a<b<c<d=e$, again there are $\binom 9   4$ such numbers
- find all subsets $\{a,b,c\}$ from $\{1,\ldots,9\}\ $ (w.l.o.g $a<b<c$), set $d:=c$, $e:=c$, to get all 5 digit numbers such that $a<b<c=d=e$, there are $\binom 9   3$

So all in all there are $ \binom 9   5 + 2 \binom 9   4 +\binom 9   3 = 462$ such numbers